# Passing API data from one page to another (Ionic 2 + Angular 2)

Tags: http, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently building a recipe app, I have a list of recipes pulling from an API. For this to work I do a http get request as below. I want to pull the `{{id}}` from the JSON and place it in the url where **(id)** is.

```
loadDetails(id) {
  if (this.details) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.details);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/' + (id) + '?_app_id=397aed16&_app_key=69e2565adcec7a6609b18bef31261e62')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.details = data;
        resolve(this.details);
      });
  });
}
```

By doing this I get this error in console the **(id) is undefined**

[image]

my .ts file that I am trying to load the recipes on is as below

```
  id: any;

  loadRecipes(){
    this.apiAuthentication.loadDetails(this.id)
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
  }
```

Any help would be great

Comment: It should probably be: `this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/' + id + '?_app_id=397aed16&_app_key=69e2565adcec7a6609b18bef31261e62')` and check if you really have a value in `id` :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I have removed the brackets although still getting undefined

Comment: does the id have a value, have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems like your `id` is not initialized that's why its coming as `undefined`. Initialize it correctly then you will be able to get the results.

e.g.

```
loadRecipes(){
    this.id = 'someValue';
    this.apiAuthentication.loadDetails(this.id)
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how would I pull through some data from JSON (API) in that, eg {{recipe.id}}

Comment: You have to call another method in order to get id I guess.